# is thre a way to find recent files with locate OR automatically update the database each time a file is created

Tags: terminal, command-line, launchd

I am on MacOS Catalina. `locate` is a great command but unfortunately, **I have difficulties to find files which have been created for example one hour ago or ten minutes ago.**

It seems that I could circumvent this issue by updating the database with a higher frequency than every 24 hours.

But the other problem is that, when I launch the command `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` in root, **it lasts much time before this command ends.**

**So I conclude that update rebuilds completly the database and doesn't update only the new files created from last `locate.updateb` execution** : indeed, this would be a big gain of time if the command was not rebuilding all the database with all the files of the system.

**Finally, I think about a simple strategy :** modidy 
`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`to force it to update for example the database every 5 minutes. But if the command `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` rebuilds all the database every 5 minutes, this doesn't make sense.

So, I would like to get feedback from people who have this kind of problem and how they solved it. I prefer to avoid using the command `mdfind` but if there is not available solution with locate and not the possibility not to have to rebuild all content each time (in my case, this would be each five minutes), I would be obliged to switch to `mdfind`.

By the way, a simple crontab launching every 5 minutes the command `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` is also allowed, isn't it ?

You could also advise me to use `find` with `-mtime` flag but find is very slow (associated with `parallel`, it might be an alternative, I don't know, actually, I am a `locate` fan since I have used it a lot on Linux).

Any clue/remark/feedback are welcome,

Regards

Comment: To perhaps provide an alternative solution to your problem, what is your actual use case here? Why do you want to know which files were created most recently?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent Apple's Spotlight file-indexing system; why not just use Spotlight via the `mdfind` command?

Comment: Seeding locate for a small directory might be doable, but spotlight is the way forward even if you need to adjust it or learn how to search by name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I prefer to avoid using the command `mdfind`

Why is that? It solves your problem with no additional work. Getting `locate` to do update constantly is going to keep your Mac busy scanning the entire hard drive almost all the time. In the meantime,

```
mdfind -name filename.txt
```

Will produce the same result with no extra work by you or by your Mac. Since macOS keeps Spotlight up to date automatically, this will find files immediately after they're created. You could even use a really short shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" ==  "" ]; then
    echo What files do you want to find?
else
    mdfind -name $1
fi
```

Then alias `locate` or some other command to call the script.

Comment: 1) `mdfind` is great, except that it does not search in some places, notably ~/Library/ which is where documents in iCloud are stored.  2) Another good use of `mdfind` is `mdfind -onlyin "$PWD" -name FOO` for when you want to find a file named "FOO" in a folder or sub-folder of the current directory.

Comment: It does search those places, by filename at least. That's what `locate` would do, so it works for this question. If you use `mdfind -name` with the name of a file on iCloud Drive, it will find matches in `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to prefer a CLI solution. I'm a frequent user of the CLI in MacOS, but we must all live with the fact that Apple does not update many of their command line tools. For example, on my Macbook Pro running Mojave, the `locate` tool doesn't support the `--version` argument, but `man locate` has a date at the bottom that was about 14 years ago. So - the `locate` tool in Catalina is not the same `locate` you've used on Linux.

That said, my *"answer"* is more along the lines of a suggestion that you consider using the "smart folder" feature in `Finder`. It allows you to filter a variety of file and folder types, and show them in `Finder`'s sidebar. This may suit your needs, or it may not. In either case, you now know that Catalina's `locate` tool is fairly old now.

Since my answer is off-topic I won't elaborate further, but there are some decent ["How-To" guides for using smart folders available online](https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/add-recent-folders-to-the-finder-sidebar-macos/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Built in utilities are not all things to all people.  Rather than trying to force `locate(1)` into something it wasn't designed for, why not investigate something like [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) or [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)?

Comment: Right now this reads more like a comment than an answer. Can you eloborate on how these tools would answer the question asked by the OP?